# Sending requests for "I Like" fan page Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I developed an application as a tab page. I would like that users using the application can send requests to their friends, automatically accepting the request I like to put on the fan page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the current user send a request to their friends using the new Requests 2.0 dialogs.  Here's the documentation for requests: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

You cannot get any "automatic" acceptance of the request, nor can you get any automatic liking of fan page.  Both of those are left for each individual user to do on their own.